# JQuery.Color workaround

Tags: jquery, css, colors, jquery-animate

I want to make a textbox "flash" using Jquery. I first wanted to use `.animate` but I've learned that animate doesn't work on colors unless using the plugin [JQuery.Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color).

The thing is that I have my reasons for not wanting to use any aditional plugins, so my question is if there is some clever workaround (that isn't ridiculously complicated).

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2EECN/215/) that demonstrates both what I want and my best attempt so far...

Comment: Why not create a CSS animation that does what you want and attach that to the toggleClass?

Comment: @Paulie_D Sure, I hadn't though about that. I'll look in to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments why not create a CSS animation that does what you want and attach that to the toggleClass?

```js
$(function() {


  var Box2 = $('.box2');


  Box2.click(function() {
    $('#tb2').toggleClass("flash");

  });

});
```

```css
.box2 {
  width: 170px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  margin: 30px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
@keyframes flash {
  0% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
.flash {
  animation-name: flash;
  animation-duration: .1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="box2">Click Me</div>
<input type="text" id="tb2"></input>
```

Comment: Your solution is actually more pretty than mine, so I'll accept yours when it becomes possible. Thanks for the help! =)

Comment: Note, after clicking once the element needs to be clicked twice before running again...because I haven't actually removed the new class. That can easily be solved by adding in an `if/else function to check if the class is already toggled and remove it. Alternatively add a`setTimeout` after the initial toggle (equal to the animation length) to remove the class again.